# Best way to schedule tasks in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, cron

I need to execute a commandline on the hour and half past the hour.
Are there any better ways to do this then like this? Maybe ones that don't involve checking the hour every second.

Timer with 1 second interval:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        For i As Integer = 0 To 24
            If TimeString = i & ":00:00" & i Then or TimeString = "0" & i & ":00:00 or If TimeString = i & "30:00:" & i Then or TimeString = "0" & i & ":30:00

            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have to create an application for this? You can use Task Scheduler (control panel) in Windows.

Comment: I'd like to bundle everything into one program so there are no other "installation" needs. I guess checking time once a second isn't really heavy on any cpu but I'm just wondering if there was an alternative because I feel that it's pretty stupid.

Comment: why don't you set the timer interval to half an hour?

Comment: Won't that make it so that if the program starts at 46 minutes past the hour that it only check at 16 minutes past?

Comment: You want to execute something if the time is zz:30 or zz:00?

Comment: Step 1 - calculate the time from now to the next hour or half hour mark

Comment: @user2376356 you want millisecond or second accuracy?

Comment: Second accuracy will do. If it stays within a 5 second accuracy after running for weeks I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - calculate the time from now to the next hour or half hour mark;

Step 2 - set your timer's elapsed period to be equal to the time calculated in Step 1;

Step 3 - when the timer ticks, reset the elapsed time to be 30 minutes and then do the work you need to do.

If the process has to run exactly on the hour / half hour recalculate the time needed in step3 rather then just setting it to 30 minutes (this will compensate for drifting).

Here is some code to calculate milliseconds to midnight; you should be able to work from there

```
Private Function MillisecondsToMidnight() As Integer

    Dim ReturnValue As Integer
    Dim ts As TimeSpan

    Dim Tomorrow As DateTime = Today.AddDays(1)
    ts = Tomorrow.Subtract(Now)

    ReturnValue = ts.TotalMilliseconds()

    ts = Nothing
    Return ReturnValue

End Function
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about it that way, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really interesting. I think now the desired functionality is totally implemented below. I tested it and I believe it works.

Supposing you trigger the whole functionality using Button1 and you want to use the Timer component we have:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim seconds As New Integer()
    Dim minutes As New Integer()
    seconds = System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds
    minutes = System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes
    Dim firstOccurrence As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero
    Do
        If seconds.Equals(60) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            seconds = seconds + 1
            firstOccurrence = firstOccurrence + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        End If
    Loop

    Do
        If minutes.Equals(59) Or minutes.Equals(29) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            minutes = minutes + 1
            firstOccurrence = firstOccurrence + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        End If
    Loop

    Timer1.Interval = (((firstOccurrence.Minutes) * 60) + ((firstOccurrence.Seconds))) * 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True


End Sub
```

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

```
    'execute your code here
    Timer1.Interval = 30 * 60 * 1000

End Sub
```

Comment: I made something similar. http://pastebin.com/1JdSBR4E timer1 is on a 30 minute interval. EDIT: just noticed that the > should be >=

Comment: Have you tried to see if my code works or it has any problems?

Comment: Can't say I have, but I don't think it'll work since your loop will just count to 60 however fast your pc will be able to run it. I also think Your private sub timer1_tick should be timer2_tick. But I'm no expert so don't believe everything I say.

Comment: Yes, that is Timer1, you are right, but the first loop will find how many seconds remain for the next minute, and the second loop how many minutes remain for the next hour or half past. But if your own code works then it is fine!